# memory management on static class

Tags: asp.net, class, memory, static

In asp, how is memory managed for a static class and method?

For example, I have a public method that used in a user session. This method and its class is static. When I use this class and method for first it constructor fire.

I want to know how long this class remain in memory:

1. To end any session
2. To end last session
3. To end application

Comment: Could you please show some code? Static classes do not have constructors, only static initializers. They look like constructors with a `static` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how long this class remain in memory:

until the restart of the IIS. ( application domain restart)

static classes/ variables in asp.net stays as long the application is tunning.

the only way to remove them is to restart the IIs.

Answer (score 0):

Static classes are in memory until Application is restarted, that means restart of IIS Application pool that web site is using.

Be aware that restart of Application pool will restart all sites that are using the pool.